# Django - Update page with ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

[Edited for more clarity]
My problem is more of an architecture problem, I have thoughts of many ways to do what I need to but can't figure out which one is correct/the best, so here it is.

I fetch some xml from a remote webserver using ajax, then parse it with jquery.What I want is that when the page is first rendered I have some "loading" gifs, one for each ajax request i'll be making , then when the data is fetched, it appears on the page.

The things is I want to have jquery post these data to the view to render it. ( This is for the other developers who will be using my app, who don't know much of javascript and prefer to write python/html to code the way they want the data to be displayed and make use of the django template engine for custom tags and stuff)

The question is how can I distinguish between the first loading of the page where we have no data and the second time where we have the data. I don't want to have to refresh the page at any time. I thought of having something in the template like :

```
{% block content %}
{% if not data %}
it's the first loading of the page,we have to fetch the data.
<p> My first item : some loading logo </p>
<script>
call a static script that gets the data then appends it to the html/post it back.
</script>
{% endif %}
{% if data %}
the data had already been fetched so we can display it, something like : 
<p> My first item : {{first item}} </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have looked on other questions but it is usually updating with data from the database. Sorry if the question is too specific but I want to really have a good design of the problem before starting to write code and I'm a bit lost. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to send the parsed data back to the server just for transforming it into Html ?

Why not just use some kind of Javascript based rendering library that can do this ? Your appliation would perform faster since you don't need to execute an extra request.

Comment: Actually, it is for facilitating the reusability of my application, since it will be used by developpers who don't know much of javascript and prefer to write python/html to write the way they want the data to be displayed. They will have usecases where they have to write "ifs" and all and they don't want to do it in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Django tags and context dict are resolved when template is rendered for the first time. 
AJAX is used to post/fetch data withoud page reload, so after AJAX request your page will not be reloaded - and django template renderer will have no possibility to show updated data.

But you could use jQuery get() or post() to retrieve rendered template from other django view and integrate it into current page.

This template must be rendered at request on /ajax/fetch/:

```
{% block content %}
{% if not data %}
    it's the first loading of the page,we have to fetch the data.
    <p> My first item : some loading logo </p>
    <script>
    call a static script that gets the data then appends it to the html/post it back.
    </script>
{% else %}
    the data had already been fetched so we can display it, something like : 
    <p> My first item : {{first item}} </p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is sitting on your main page:

```
<script [include jquery here]></script>
<script>         
    $(function(){
        $("#get_data_please").click(function(){
            $.get('/ajax/fetch/', function(data) {
                // this is called on ajax success
                $('#ajax_result').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
...
<a href="#" id="get_data_please">Click to get data</a>
<div id="ajax_result">
    Here all will be loaded
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't get it very well. First, you say that I should have two templates? one rendered at the beginning and the other after the request?I see that the first one to be rendered is the one you wrote and then it calls the ajax/fetch but then whats the use of the template i wrote?. Also, I in your script I get that I have to click a link to get the data but i don't want that, i need the data to be updated automatically (i'll have some comet probably). I'm sorry if i'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, you have two templates. First for main page, which contains a placeholder(<div id="ajax_result"></div>) and some other stuff which is static (filled once when you render a page). Second template is for filling by django template renderer with results of every ajax request - it can be called by ajax many times for updating inner data without needing of full reload of main template. You can think of it like as inner html-frame. Also you can trigger filling placeholder <div> not just by clicking on link - it can be timer, for example-just call $.get() and fill <div> with html of server reply